# Rewrite statement using symbols

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have a statement: Every real number has a unique multiplicative inverse.

My answer is ($\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$)($\exists! y \in \mathbb{R}$)($xy = 1$). Is this correct? Thank you! Please do not care about the truth value of the statement, I know it is wrong because x must be nonzero.
I was not sure about the unique part.

Comment: It is correct , perhaps apart from the parantheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good, although I'm not sure about the way you use parentheses.  I tend to use commas:$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists!y\in\mathbb{R},xy=1.$$
The "exists unique" quantifier could also be expanded out, depending on what you're going to do with this formalized statement:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists y\in\mathbb{R},xy=1\wedge(\forall y'\in\mathbb{R},xy'=1\to y'=y).$$